How can we maintain what we achieved in June 2012?
After a successful June goal it seems that we have dropped the ball. With less than 2 weeks into July, our questions/day is under 2, and visits/day under 200:

How can we recover? What should we do in order to regain the momentum we had in June? 
September will be a particularly important month for us, since it is the month school resumes at many universities. As an academic SE, this should correspond to an increase in visitors. To prepare, we should have the site shinning and glowing by the end of August. Any suggestions for an August goal?

I really like the idea of striving to keep our questions per day at 3.0 or more. If we can do that for the rest of the year while keeping answer ratio and percentage answered healthy, I think the site will be on a really good footing for the future.
I really liked the idea that @artem had for setting personal targets for asking questions. I think that having a good mix of high quality questions from high-rep users is a great way to keep the site humming along at a high standard in the early days.
In terms of visits per day, there were a couple of successful shares of questions on reddit in June. Once they leave the two week moving average, visits per day drop down to their baseline level. I think the baseline level is increasing, but it is just that we are not so huge that social network spikes don't have a noticeable effect. There might also be a northern hemisphere vacation effect. 

I think the vacation effect is significant. Even my adsense earnings are down this month

@jeromy I guess you have to share the site more aggressively in the southern hemisphere ;).

Can't commit for July but would definitely get 20 questions in August (unless hit by a bus with 90%+ probability)
